# Facebook Open Graph Custom Actions on the Fly

Tags: facebook

I am giving a look to the Open Graph API. From what I see so far we must set up the actions and objects in the App configuration on Facebook.

What I am looking for is to set up actions and objects on the fly using PHP or Javascript.

I want to build an application that will be integrated in a Social Networking CMS. I do not want my customers to set up each action and object on the Dev App, it could take forever. I simply want to fire them with PHP based on the different actions that can be done in this CMS (such as: watch a video, listen music, chatting with friends etc.. etc.. )

Is there a way to create actions on the fly with PHP or Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No - each action you setup has to be approved by Facebook before it can be used outside the developers of your application.

Comment: I think the way is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/connections/ . But I do not clearly understand how it actually works...?!

Comment: Thats for creating instances of an approved action for a user. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ - should clear things up for you.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same question, seems to be buried in the opengraph section:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/

Comment: nav's original answer is correct. The question is about defining an action for an application, which is not the same as publishing an action instance for a user.